# PHP web crawler, check URL for path

Tags: php, url, path, web-crawler, bots

I'm writing a simple web crawler to grab some links from a site. 
I need to check the returned links to make sure I selectively collect what I want.

For example, here's a few links returned from http://www.polygon.com/

[0] http://www.polygon.com/2015/5/15/8613113/destiny-queens-wrath-bounties-ether-key-guide#comments

[1] http://www.polygon.com/videos

[2] http://www.polygon.com/2015/5/15/8613113/destiny-queens-wrath-bounties-ether-key-guide

[3] http://www.polygon.com/features

so link 0 and 2 are links I want to grab, 1 and 3 we don't want. there's an obvious visual distinction between the links so how would I compare them?

How would I check to make sure I don't return 1 and 3? ideally i'd like to be able to input something so it could adapt to any site.

I was thinking I need to check the link to make sure its past /2015/ etc but I'm pretty lost.

here's the PHP code i'm using to grab links:

```
<?php

$source_url = 'http://www.polygon.com/';
$html = file_get_contents($source_url);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $input_url = $link->getAttribute('href');
    echo $input_url . "<br>";   
}
?>
```

Comment: A simple `strpos($input_url, '/2015/') >= (strlen($source_url)-1)` would do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like regular expressions would be helpful here.
You could say, for instance:

```
/* if $input_url contains a 4 digit year, slash, number(s), slash, number(s) */
if (preg_match("/\/20\d\d\/\d+\/\d+\/",$input_url)) {
  echo $input_url . "<br>";
}
```